# How to organize Favorite Links in Vista Explorer?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I have about 30 links in my Favorite Links section of Vista Explorer and they are starting to get hard to find.

Is there a way to organize them according to importance or group them with color, etc.?

My current solution is to name them things like aaa-webs and bbb-audio, and I'm also using [the free FileBoxExtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp) which gives me another area to organize favorites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag/drop them, so they can be in whichever order you like.

Comment: yes I was doing that but then to group them I needed to put them alphabetize them again, which destroys my ordering, figured out you can apply icons for a type of grouping, would be nice to make some green, some yellow, etc. a third-party tool that does this would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you don't want to install a 3rd-party program is to just have one folder in you favorite links. In that folder you have shortcuts to all your locations. That way you can order them like everything else in explorer.

This requires 1 more click but I'm just thinking outside the box here. :)

Answer (score -2):

By far the best way to organise favourites is to use a web-based tool like http://delicious.com - try it once and you'll never look back.

Comment: right, but I mean windows explorer favorites, e.g. c:\audio etc. not internet bookmarks.